# How to read from .dat file and populate in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, edt

I need to read data from `scores.dat` file and pop it into a `JTable`, here is more info:

1. `Scores.dat` looks like

   ```
   Team  Name   Score1    Score2
   Red    John    55        7
   Blue   Michael 33        6
   Green  Burrs   55        5
   ```

   location = `C:\Documents\scores.dat`
2. The first row is column names. So need to Pop column names into 1st row of the table.
3. `Scores.dat` is dynamic, rows are added/deleted with user action.
4. Also, I need a button "Top Scorer" below the table, which when clicked upon, highlights row with highest score.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author singh_000
 */
public class SampleJTableDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    /**
     * Creates new form OrderMateRequestForm
     */
    public SampleJTableDemo() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        //headers for the table
        String[] columns = new String[]{
            "Team", "Name", "Score1", "Score2"//Todo: pop names from 1st row from scores.dat
        };

        //actual data for the table in a 2d array
        Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
            {"Red", "John", 40.0, 7},
            {"Blue", "Rambo", 70.0, 6},
            {"Gree", "Zorro", 60.0, 7},
            {"Black", "Curran", 70.0, 5},};

        final Class[] columnClass = new Class[]{
            String.class, String.class, Double.class, Integer.class
        };
        //create table model with data
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns) {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return columnClass[columnIndex];
            }
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
//        contentPane.add(table);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
        separator.setVisible(true);
        contentPane.add(separator);
        //add the table to the frame
//        this.add(new JScrollPane(table));
//ToDO: Add buton for top scorer        
JButton button = new JButton("Top Scorer");
        button.setVisible(true);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        this.setTitle("Score-List");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SampleJTableDemo();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Specifically: you don't just post your **assignment** and some code; to then expect us to read all your code to understand where exactly it is not matching up your homework. So far, this reads like: "here is the template my teacher gave me. fill it with code". Nope.

Comment: To make it easier for people to test the [mcve] suggested by @GhostCat, presume the data has already been read into a `String` and hard code that `String` in the MCVE. Limit the data to just two entries in order to keep it short.

Comment: BTW - *"read from .dat file and populate in JTable?"* - which part are you having trouble with, the reading or the populating? If 'both' then you need to split the problem down in two parts, and get each working separately.

Comment: @AndrewThompson populating data, as first row in .dat file is all strings (column Names) and subsequent rows contains integers as well. I have used BufferReader to read data. While I created Team object (params name, score1, score2). When i read first line, I'm trying to set Team parameters but getting NumberFormat Exception as Team.setScore1(int) expects integer while readLine() from BufferReader contains strings (Column Names)

Comment: Please focus on a single question.

Comment: *"populating data.."* So hard code the data in a `String` in the MCVE. Turn it into an input stream using `new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes());`. Then try reading the data from it using a `new Scanner(inputStream)`. A [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) has lots of ways to read data.

Comment: `I have used BufferReader` - @AndrewThompson, you can also use a StringReader( String ) instead of changing all the code to use a Scanner and InputStream to hard code data for simple tests to post on the forum.

Comment: @camickr I suggested `Scanner` because the data is apparently a mixture of string, integer and double values. `Scanner` has methods for reading each.

Answer (score 0):

> When i read first line, I'm trying to set Team parameters but getting NumberFormat Exception as Team.setScore1(int) expects integer while readLine() from BufferReader contains strings (Column Names)

So when you read the first line you parse the data into Strings

```
String[] columnNames = line.split(" ");
```

When you read the additional lines you need to convert the String data to the proper datatype:

```
String[] lineData = theNextLine.split(" " );
String team = lineData[0];
String name = lineData[1];
Double score1 = Double.parseDouble( lineData[2] );
Integer score2 = Integer.parseInt( lineData[3] );
```

Now you can use the addRow(...) method of the DefaultTableModel to add the data to the table.